# MVC Nested DisplayForModel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't get nested DisplayForModel to work at all, I have tried everything. All display templates are in the correct DisplayTemplates folder.

The ratings file just never gets called, although if I do `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Likes, "Ratings")` it would call it correctly but obviously only pass the likes property through, anyone know what is going on here?

Index file, works fine:

```
@model IList<UploadedSongViewModel>

<section id="music-grid">
    <div class="container">
        @Html.DisplayForModel() //Works fine
    </div>
</section>
```

UploadedSongViewModel template:

```
@model UploadedSongViewModel
<div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
    @Html.DisplayForModel("Ratings") //Never calling the ratings display template
</div>
```

Ratings file:

```
<span class="like-percentage" data-likes="@Model.Likes" data-dislikes="@Model.Dislikes">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Like percentage">
    </i>
</span>
```

Comment: Unless your question is about how ASP.NET implements the MVC pattern, please try to use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] in the future. The model-view-controller tag is meant for general questions about the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Never calling the ratings display template

That is by design.  The MVC engine tags each object it renders by type by setting the `TemplateInfo.Visited()` method.  If it's already visited the model, it won't *visit* it again (to avoid stack overflows / infinite loops).  Simply changing it to the following should work (can't test atm).

```
@model UploadedSongViewModel
<div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m, "Ratings") 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. That explains the problem.

I tried your answer as well but it's still not calling. Also isn't that just the same as `@Html.DisplayForModel("Ratings")`?.

Comment: Apparently it is the same, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Since you're using just a display template, I suppose you could `@{Html.RenderPartial("Ratings", Model);}` but the ratings location would be slightly different.

Comment: Ye. I think that is best. Thanks.